# SQL Server : remove "decimals" from nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data that has come in as a `nvarchar`. Clearly the data was originally converted from a numeric based datatype. For example I have values that are `17.0000000`. I would like to remove these trailing zeros so that it is just "17". I do need the output in either `varchar` or `nvarchar`.

Comment: What to do with 17.10000?   17.1 or 17 ?

Comment: if it is anything but a 0 i would like to preserve the value. so in your example i would want the "17.1"

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of the decimal and zeros afterwards using:

```
select (case when col like '%.0%' and col not like '%.%[^0]%'
             then left(col, charindex('.', col) - 1)
             when col like '%.%0'
             then replace(rtrim(replace(col, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
             else col
        end)
```

Note:  This assumes that the value is strictly numeric (hence doesn't have its own spaces).

However, I would suggest that you convert the value to an appropriate `numeric`/`decimal` type.

Comment: I cant use the appropriate numeric/decimal because the vendors software is using a string comparison on the data to preform some tasks. The above works great for me. However, in the instance of 17.5 it is still adding trailing zeros such as "17.500000" to where I need "17.5". How can I adapt for this.

Comment: Your second approach allows you to get rid of the first by just applying the second again, to simplify the complete expression a bit: `replace(rtrim(replace(rtrim(replace(col, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'), '.', ' ')), ' ', '.')`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option if 2012+

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([StrValue] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('17.00000')
,('17.10000')
,('.1')
,('.0')
,('Cat')
,('07/29/2017')

Select * 
      ,NewVal = coalesce(convert(varchar(50),try_convert(float,StrValue)),StrValue)
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
StrValue    NewVal
17.00000    17
17.10000    17.1
.1          0.1
.0          0
Cat         Cat
07/29/2017  07/29/2017
```

Comment: Nice, But this will change `.1` to `0.1` and `.0` to `0` and ... ;).

Comment: @shA.t Yes it does.

Comment: @shA.t See additional data in answer

Comment: I see, and results of Gordon's answer is `.1` for `.1` and an empty string for `.0` that I think that's true ;).

Comment: @shA.t Op's comment  "if it is anything but a 0 i would like to preserve the value"   Perhaps I have a different read on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT('17.0000000',CHARINDEX('17.0000000','.')-1)
```

I've hardcoded the value here but you would replace that with your column name

Answer (score 0):

A double cast will also get rid of the trailing zeros

```
select cast(cast('17.0000000' as float) as varchar)
union
select cast(cast('17.1000000' as float) as varchar)
```

results in

```
17
17.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with out using `case` can be:

```
select col
    , reverse(                      -- use reverse to find from right
        substring(
            reverse(col), 
            patindex(               -- finding first char that is not `0`
                '%[^0]%', 
                reverse(col)) + 
            patindex(               -- finding first char that is not `.` after removing trailing `0`s
                '%[^.]%', 
                substring(          -- remove trailing `0`s
                    reverse(col), 
                    patindex('%[^0]%', reverse(col)), 
                    len(col)) + 'x') - 1,     -- Note: I add `'x'` to avoid error
            len(col)))
from t;
```

[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/10005)